# Unity 3d Event Trigger setting gameobject.active to false

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I m a newbie to Unity. After creating a simple scene with few objects, I want to hide an oject  on pointer exit.
I learnt by adding Trigger Event with object's component and on pointer enter, I managed to find setActive (bool) under gameobject. But don't know how to set active false on pointer exit. There is no such function in Event Trigger  component.
Anyone plz help.

Answer (score 0):

you can add on your Script

```
void IPointerExitHandler.OnPointerExit (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    OnPointerExit(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Does this hv a command to set object active to false?

Comment: add in the fonction OnPointerExit:

"this.GameObject.SetActive(false);"

Comment: Oops I get error: OnPointerExit does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to use unity 3d's built in events than writing scripts. For a non programmers like me, unity3d is kind enough to give superb options without scripting.
1. Disable rendering of the object A
2. On object B add event, under point enter choose object A and in function choose enable rendering.
It's done. Whenever pointer enters B object A wil be visible and it is easy to make further invisible while point exit event.